# How to wrap nominated substrings in html tags?

Tags: php, tags, str-replace, substring

I need to case-insensitively target substrings and wrap them in `<strong></strong>` tags:

Example:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo "abcdefABCDEF";
```

If I search for "a" (example: index.php?q=a), the output will embolden the all occurrences of "a" and "A" like this:

```
<strong>a</strong>bcdef<strong>A</strong>BCDEF
```

How do I insert these tags into the string?

Comment: *"How i do this in PHP?"*: the first step is to do some research and to try something .

Comment: In this simple example you don't need regex. And for most cases you shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$q = 'o';
$original_string = 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.';

echo str_ireplace($q, '<strong>' . $q . '</strong>', $original_string);
```

Comment: One issue with this method is that it could alter the case of the matching substring to match the case of $q. That might be an undesirable result if, for example, you're dealing with the first word of a sentence. In that case, use preg_replace instead which wraps the original text, rather than replacing it with the text being searched for.

Answer (score 1):

Considering using `preg_replace()` if you are intending to search and replace content with HTML tags. You'll find it's more powerful than `str_ireplace()`

```
echo preg_replace('/([aA])/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $_GET['q']);
```

Comment: Note that Martin answer is more simple (and faster). As an aside, you don't have to use a capture group, you can refer to the whole match with `$0` in the replacement string. You can also use the case insensitive modifier i: `/a/i`

Comment: @Julio Cesar Regular expressions is what you really want to learn when searching and replacing. See [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Really? <°))))))))))))>

Comment: $pattern = $_GET['q'];
$string= "abcdefABCDEF";
echo preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/i', '<strong>'.$0.'</strong>', $string);